# WPF ComboBox Undo Exception on Ctrl+Z (with Focus on SelectionChanged), Why?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-4.0, combobox, undo

Well, someone can tell me why this exception occurs in these conditions?

`Test Window`

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox
        Name="cmbTest"
        IsEditable="True"
        SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    </ComboBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
Class MainWindow

  Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim source As New ObservableCollection(Of String)()
    source.Add("AAA")
    source.Add("BBB")
    source.Add("CCC")
    cmbTest.ItemsSource = source
  End Sub

  Private Sub ComboBox_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)
    Keyboard.Focus(cmbTest)
  End Sub

End Class
```

Now, if you type `AAA` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, `ComboBox` control raise this exception:

> Cannot Undo or Redo while undo unit is open.

Someone can explain why?!? How it would be possible to avoid it?

Comment: I have the same problem when moving focus in TextBox.TextChanged. If I put focus back manually (mouse/shiftTab) then Ctrl-Z crashes as well.. :s

Comment: For that particular problem I currently managed to bypass the problem when doin gthe Focus on the UIThread after I invoked it from a Timer.. >.< Just to see if it'd work. Working on more..

Answer (score 0):

"The Undo method does not work with the KeyPress or TextChanged events."
This has gotten me before.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.undo.aspx